# Ways to compute values from multiple dataframes and organize it into one consolidated dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes spanning from 2015/09 - 2021/12 as

[image]

and each dataframe looks like this

```
    address     balance
0   0xb794f5ea0 7504999.894348815
1   0xab7c74abc 1000000.004137971
2   0xdec042a90 5461102.0
3   0xd24400ae8 352884.012859933
4   0x2910543af 217051.397233717
5   0xcafb10ee6 211851.993504593
6   0x167a9333b 164052.961890484
7   0x32be343b9 113179.682105883
8   0xfbb1b73c4 69408.795824975
9   0x7180eb39a 3012.654675749
10  0x0a869d79a 85.171503551
11  0x61edcdf5b 5.0
12  0x2903cadbe 0.985099383
13  0xdd51f01d9 0.002366924
..      ....        ....
```

I want to calculate, let's say, the sum of all balance per date and consolidate into one dataframe as

```
date        balance_sum
2015-09-31  xx
2015-12-31  xx 
2016-03-31  xx 
...
2021-12-31  xx
```

Is there a way to do this operation? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you have a list of dates?

Comment: It's a snapshot, so for instance, anything that belongs to the dataframe "exchanges_2015_09" will be from 2015-09-30.

Comment: I can manually create quarters by. pd.date_range('2015-09-30', periods=26, freq='Q'), i just have to insert the computed values

Comment: Run a for loop and calculate the mean of balance_sum in every data frame and append it to a dict convert it to a DataFrame

Comment: Would you be able to share the code? I am fairly new to python, unfortunately.... :(. and it's not the mean  of balance sum, it's just the sum..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm running a for loop over all the dataframes, appending the sum to a list and then creating a dictionary with date as keys and sum as values, finally I'm converting dict to DataFrame.

```
balance_sum = []
for i in [exchanges_2015_09, exchanges_2015_09 ....]:
    balance_sum.append(i['balance_sum'].sum())

data = dict(zip(pd.date_range('2015-09-30', periods=26, freq='Q'), balance_sum))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!! I had to add this after data, , orient='index'.